# Seeking Advice on LLM for reading charts and tables in pdf files

Tags: pdf, charts, large-language-model

I'm diving into a project that involves using a LLM to answer questions based on various local documents stored in PDF format. My main challenge lies in finding the most effective method or tools that enable the LLM to accurately interpret charts and tables containing text information (particularly figures) within these documents. Of course, I don't expect reading charts with only bars and bubbles without any text information.

I tried to feed pdf documents to ChatGPT directly. Unfortunately, ChatGPT can not reading the charts contained in those pdf files correctly.

Comment: Well, as I see it you need to fine-tune an LLM for this task. How that'd be doable is a tough question, depends on how the figures are stored... If they are just pictures stored in the PDF then I guess you have no better option than detecting what is on the picture first (e.g. with a CNN) but this'd just be too inconvenient. If you have the graphs stored as SVG formats or LaTeX code, that could work with LLM fine tuning